# How to call force:navigateToComponent from Salesforce Lightning Custom Object List View

Tags: lightning, javascript, navigatetocomponent

How could I call `force:navigateToComponent` from a Salesforce Lightning Custom Object List View?

If I try and add a `Custom Button or Link` which has a Behavior of `Execute JavaScript` it displays a warning:

> JavaScript custom buttons may reduce application security and block compatibility with Lightning Experience. We advise against using these buttons.

Comment: If you can give me why your'e trying to navigate I can try adding any more relevant details in my answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off Starting in API version 43.0, the force:navigateToComponent event is [deprecated](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/force:navigateToComponent/documentation). Salesforce recommends implementing the lightning:isUrlAddressable interface on your target component and navigating to the component using lightning:navigation component with the standard__component page type instead. This generates a route in the format `/cmp/{componentName}?myAttr=attrValue`.

The issue here is you cannot invoke a lightning component from the list views. It has to be something like a vfpage and a container lightning component but **lightning:isUrlAddressable aren’t [supported](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/summer18/release-notes/rn_lc_components_navigation.htm) in other containers, such as Lightning Components for Visualforce, Lightning Out, or Communities**. This is true even if you access these containers inside Lightning Experience or the Salesforce mobile app.

> Apart from that Javascript buttons aren't supported in lightning. Look
>   at [Embrace Lightning and Leave JavaScript Buttons Behind](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/en/content/learn/modules/lex_javascript_button_migration/lex_javascript_button_migration_intro)